# How to delete hierarchical structure using mongoose ,Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

My hierarchy of schema is......
**`List -> Items -> (attachements,comments,labels)`**

Que: So if I want to delete a list, All referenced(Hierarchical) elements should be **deleted**.Here (**attachements,comments,labels**) are referenced to **Item** and Item referenced to **List**.So give me suggestions to do that.
Schemas:

```
List:{
 list_title: {type: String, required: true},
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date
}
Item:{
 item_title: {type: String, required: true},
  discription:{type: String},
  label : {type:Array ,label_id : String },
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date,
  _list: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'List'}
}
Comment:{
  comment:{type:String},
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date,
  entity_id : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:''},
  model : {type : String ,enum : ['Item','File'] }
}
Attachment:{
   title : [{type : String}],
     // files: [String],
       path : [String],
      make_cover : {type : Boolean },
    _item: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Item'}
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

When you make a search with Mongoose, you receive Mongoose objects. Every Mongoose object has all the information stored in the document it represents (list -> Items -> (attachments, comments, labels)
When you have the object you want to work with in Node.js, you can remove in the object all elements you don't need anymore, and at the end, you can call .save() method and all the changes you made in the object will be saved in MongoDB

Example:

```
myCollection.findOne({name: "myName"},  function(err, obj) {
    // obj is the Mongoose object with all the information in the document in DB
    // Here you can remove elements from obj, imagine you want to remove first item in the first element of List
    obj.List[0].splice(0, 1);
    // Finally, we save changes in DB
    obj.save();
})
```

Comment: by doing that, only those info will be deleted which is associated with that list.But i want to delete also attachments, comments, labels.

Comment: It was only an example. What I meant is that you can remove wathever you want in that object (including attachments, comments, ....) and when you call the .save() method of the object, all those elements will be removed in the DB. Try it and let me know if it works for you

Comment: I got an error :TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined

Comment: As I told you, it was an example. Acording to your schema, List is not a list :S, so modify the elements that really exist :)